# What is the expected pattern for exposing make variables from a custom bazel toolchain?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I'm trying to expose a make variable to a genrule so that I can pass along some information from toolchain selection to a custom rule. In this case it is the object file format that corresponds to the currently selected toolchain for my language (one of MachO/ELF/PE).

I have figured out that if I expose the `TemplateVariableInfo` on a particular rule, and then depend on that rule in my genrule's toolchain attribute, then I get the desired behavior. But I don't see how to combine this with toolchain resolution other than manually through a rule whose sole purpose is to expose the make variables. This is because I don't control the implementation of the `toolchain_type` rule and thus cannot make it return the `TemplateVariableInfo`.

If I do it this way then when defining a target I need to supply a different label into the toolchains attribute than I do for when I'm defining a rule. Maybe this is the best pattern, but it seems if that is the case then why are the things providing `Make Variables` supplied in the `toolchain` attribute if they have nothing to do with toolchains?

Comment: The extra rule I ended up implementing that I feel should somehow be not needed: https://github.com/endobson/yaspl2/commit/e0d2c867ec17b531babd4c1938d6594b0bbc9b4e#diff-ba0f7cbbe3c1ad98e36da7a944be419c1308fe5cb1e45c9d1f6c726ff907024bR220